# Перегрузка функций для вывода содержания последовательностей

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Написал  функцию для вывода содержаний контейнера в удобном для себя формате

```
template < class C >
void show(const C& cont, size_t n = 25, const char* del = " ")
{
    size_t i = 1;
    for (typename C::value_type  val : cont) {
        std::cout << val << del;
        if (!(i % n))  std::cout <<'\n';
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Как перегрузить show для указателей на массив?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "указателями на массив"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так достаточно

```
template < class C >
void show(const C& cont, size_t n = 25, const char* del = " ")
{
    size_t i = 1;
    for (auto val : cont) {
        std::cout << val << del;
        if (!(i % n))  std::cout <<'\n';
        ++i;
    }
}
```

[Проверьте](https://ideone.com/0aCVTZ) -

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
show(a,5);
```

вполне работает...

Ну, или как вариант для больших элементов, которые не хочется передавать по значению -

```
    for (const auto& val : cont) {
```

Comment: Harry  так гораздо лучше - спасибо!

Comment: @Harry Может стоит добавить const в цикле?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Просто `const` - бессмысленно: тогда уж `const auto&`.

Answer (score 2):

Если под "указателями на массив" вы имели в виду действительно буквально указатели на массив, т.е. сущности типа `T (*)[N]`, то перегрузка могла бы выглядеть так

```
template < class E, size_t N >
void show(E (*cont)[N], size_t n = 25, const char* del = " ")
{
    size_t i = 1;
    for (auto val : *cont) {
        std::cout << val << del;
        if (!(i % n))  std::cout <<'\n';
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Однако смысла в этом нет, ибо уже существующая ваша реализация умеет работать с массивами и какие-то перегрузки для "указателей на массив" вам тут не нужны вообще.

Подозреваю, что вам нужна перегрузка для обычных указателей на *элемент* массива. Такую перегрузку невозможно сделать полностью аналогичной существующей, ибо по указателю на элемент массива невозможно определить его размер. Поэтому в таком случае размер придется передавать вручную, отдельным переметром

```
template < class E >
void show(const E cont[], size_t N, size_t n = 25, const char* del = " ")
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        auto val = cont[i];
        std::cout << val << del;
        if (!((i + 1) % n))  std::cout <<'\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: да, я еше не изучал  C++11, потому недогодался использовать auto. Спасибо